# Unable to set a background image on UWP C++ project with XAML

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I've completed a couple of projects using Visual Studio 2019 and C# with no problem. I am currently learning C++ and as part of the process, I am recreating a C# UWP application with C++. I haven't gotten to the C++ yet. I'm just about done with the XAML and this also uses Visual State Manager but the problem is that I am unable to use an image as the background for the root StackPanel.

This works perfectly fine on the C# project and I have been looking at the code side by side for a while and even tried setting it in Blend with various images but the only result is a plain white background instead of the image.

I can set a background color directly on the StackPanel and that works fine but no images. I have placed the images in the Assets folder and also the Assets Filter.

This is the code, with a test image, that works well with the C# project but the same does not want to work with the C++ one.

```
<Setter Target="stackPanel.(Panel.Background)">
<Setter.Value>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/testImage.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Setter.Value>
```

On the C# Project, this code is in each of the Visual State groups, and as said before, it works fine but the C++ project only gives a white background. When this code is removed, it uses the StackPanel color as the background. there's no change if I remove the background color either.

It also doesn't work if I create App resources for the background images in App.xaml and point to them. same result.

Note that the only thing that was changed since the creation of the project is the MainPage.xaml and App.xaml. I haven't touched anything else yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I have finally figured it out. I needed to copy the files into the projects' Assets folder and then copy the files from that specific folder to the Filters. It would not work any other way. Sorted!